# Access AJAX data on node.js server

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, server

I am building an app using node.js and wanted to see how I could access my AJAX GET request data on the server side. Example:

Client side AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/test",
    type: "GET",
    data: {email: 'myemail@gmail.com', name: 'george'}, //send this to server
    success: function() {

    },
    error: function() {

    }

});
```

Server side API

```
router.get('/api/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body) //should print data from AJAX request; currently returns empty {}
});
```

However, I keep getting an empty object when I try to access the data.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried sending it directly in the url instead of the `data` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use post instead get:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/test",
    type: "POST",
    data: {email: 'myemail@gmail.com', name: 'george'}, //send this to server
    success: function() {

    },
    error: function() {

    }

});
```

And `router.post()`.

Comment: Hi - I am actually trying to console log the data on the server side, not the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I got it - it's `console.log(req.query)`